# Codeigniter sync database tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Iam using codeigniter POS application. POS installed on localhost. I have 2 showrooms and 1 warehouse, warehouse also have codeigniter program running online(www.xyz.com) and I need to transfer goods between showroom-warehouse.

im using following steps;

1) showroom POS (in localhost) send good request to warehouse(online). I placed product request form in the online warehouse system.
2) warehouse receive request note and prepare goods.
3) warehouse send goods physically and update system.
4) showroom revive goods and need to stock In (update) using warehouse system (online-to-localhost) ; how can I do this.
ex: showroom user can see received goods from the warehouse system. then user needs to update stock in localhost by clicking "Add stock" in  warehouse system.

please advice me.

Comment: If you're simply needing advice on how to have communication between servers, you can achieve this in multiple ways. You could use a REST API, cURL, ssh connections, etc, etc.

Comment: @BrianGottier please give me some example link ..

Comment: go with crone jobs